# Why use getTransaction or getSignatureStatus for tx confirmation?

Tags: web3.js, sendandconfirmrawtransaction

Why would I do polling with `getTransaction` or `getSignatureStatus`, when I can just use `sendAndConfirm` to check the tx status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see polling to be useful if I wanted to display the TX state in realtime.

Although it seems like `sendAndConfirm` is an abstracted method on top of `getSignatureStatus` polling

Answer 1:

> You can't sendAndConfirm on the frontend using the wallet adapter. You
> gotta use the wallet's sign method, then send the signed transaction,
> and thus you will have to poll the transaction status to check for
> inclusion in a block

Answer 2

> It's useful for fault tolerance -- If you're sending a tx from a server w/ sendAndConfirm, and the server crashes, when you start up again, you have no idea of which transactions were in progress.

More context and answers in this [twitter thread](https://twitter.com/burger606/status/1662882652230242305?s=20).